# What is the feasibility of High Resolution (< 5m) Hyper spectral Imaging satellite?

Tags: artificial-satellite, imaging, earth-observation, remote-sensing

Many companies are coming up with claim of less than 5m resolution of hyper spectral imagery, although the payloads of such caliber could be built, I have come to the understanding that SNR would be too poor to extract any useful analytics. Does anyone know of a payload with high resolution imaging capabilities, while the detectors are providing good SNR. Do any techniques exist to make it viable.

Comment: what counts as high-resolution?

Comment: @ErinAnne It seems the asker is considering <5m (presumably per-pixel) as "high-resolution"

Comment: Planet Labs "Dove" satellites are cube-sat sized and priced (inexpensive) and are capable of multi-spectral imaging at a 3m ground resolution.

Comment: @Dragongeek Indeed. I think that we'll have to figure out where "multi-spectral ends and [hypserspectral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperspectral_imaging) begins, which may (or may not) mean that this question needs clarification. It it were me, I'd ask this in Earth Science SE where folks deal with multispectral and hyperspectral Earth imaging data routinely and know their way around the terminology.